# Inno Setup How to make a task always checked?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm working on an Inno Setup script for my installer. My question is, how can I make a task always checked? That is, I want the task to appear, by maybe it's checked and greyed out, so the user cannot uncheck it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable a task programmatically only:

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: fixed; Description: "Fixed task"
Name: notfixed; Description: "Not fixed task"

[Code]

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    { Only now is the TasksList populated }
    WizardForm.TasksList.ItemEnabled[0] := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Fixed task]

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for!